# How to make fragment layout inside activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to make activity and fragment layouts?

I have main activity layout, wich contains 4 fragments (they are staggered).
I write two of them. They are similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="net.user.app.MainActivity"
android:layout_row="1"
android:layout_column="6"
android:layout_weight="10"
>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0">

    <fragment
        android:name="net.company.app.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"

        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout" /> 

 <fragment
        android:name="net.company.app.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"

        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout" /> 


</GridLayout>
```

So, i write code of fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyFragment">
android:background="@drawable/back">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="11">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvView"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:text="Some Content"
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etText"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibButton"
        android:background="#b69292"
         />
</GridLayout>
```

But, when i run app- it looks very bad: Image button looks very small.
As i understand,  width of `ImageButton` will be 50dp? Or, width will vary with respect to size of the fragment in the activity?

How to make fragment layout inside activity? 
Maybe, you tak eme some tutorial links about this case?

Comment: Why are you making your views fixed sizes?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using fragment layout, you can use framelayout and then you can write this in your activity:

```
YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, yourFragment).commit();
```

Here, frame_layout is the FrameLayout tag in your activity's xml file. 
This is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your application to run on different screen sizes, you should define views with generic sizes such as `wrap_content` and `match_parent`, this will help in making your application more dynamic for different screen sizes.

Here is a simple example for that:
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write